# Dicionário e funções Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Não entendo porque o código a seguir fala que está recebendo mais de um valor pro mesmo parâmetro.

```
def foo(name, **kwds):
    return 'name' in kwds
foo(1, **{'name' : 2})´
```

> TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Mas quando uso desse outro jeito dá certo:

```
def foo(name, /, **kwds):
    return 'name' in kwds
foo(1, **{'name' : 2})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Primeiro, vamos ver o que a `/` faz.

Se você declara uma função como essa:

```
def f(a, b):
    print(a, b)
```

É possível chamá-la de várias maneiras diferentes:

```
# passando os parâmetros posicionais
f(1, 2) # 1 2

# usando os nomes dos parâmetros
f(a=1, b=2) # 1 2

# usando os nomes, podemos inclusive passá-los em qualquer ordem
f(b=2, a=1) # 1 2
```

Mas se usarmos a `/` na declaração dos parâmetros ([recurso que foi adicionado no Python 3.8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)), isso quer dizer que todos os argumentos antes da `/` não podem ser passados usando-se os nomes. Veja a diferença para o exemplo anterior:

```
def f(a, b, /): # "a" e "b" não podem ser passados com nomes
    print(a, b)

# passando os parâmetros posicionais, funciona
f(1, 2) # 1 2

# usando os nomes, dá erro
f(a=1, b=2) # TypeError: f() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'a, b'
```

E qualquer parâmetro que estiver depois da `/` pode ser passado com ou sem o nome:

```
def f(a, b, /, c, d):
    print(a, b, c, d)

# "c" e "d" podem ser passados posicionalmente
f(1, 2, 3, 4) # 1 2 3 4

# "c" e "d" podem ser passados com os nomes
f(1, 2, c=3, d=4) # 1 2 3 4
f(1, 2, d=4, c=3) # 1 2 3 4

# "a" e "b" não podem ser passados com nomes
f(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4) # TypeError: f() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'a, b'
```

---

Agora, se usarmos *keyword arguments*:

```
def foo(name, **kwds):
    print(name, kwds)
```

Ao chamar `foo(1, **{'name' : 2})`, no fundo é o mesmo que fazer `foo(1, name=2)` (veja [este exemplo na documentação](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-argument)). Mas como o primeiro parâmetro se chama `name`, então é como se eu estivesse fazendo `foo(name=1, name=2)`. Daí a mensagem de erro: "*foo() got multiple values for argument 'name'*", pois ele entende que estou passando dois valores diferentes para `name`.

Já usando a `/`:

```
def foo(name, /, **kwds):
    print(name, kwds)

foo(1, **{'name' : 2}) # 1 {'name': 2}
foo(1, name=2) # 1 {'name': 2}
```

Agora funciona porque, como a `/` indica que o parâmetro `name` é apenas posicional, o nome dele (`name`) pode ser usado nos *keyword arguments*, sem a possibilidade de "colisão" de nomes.

Inclusive este exemplo é citado na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters):

> *Since the parameters to the left of `/` are not exposed as possible keywords, the parameters names remain available for use in `**kwargs`:*
>
> ```
> >>> def f(a, b, /, **kwargs):
> ...     print(a, b, kwargs)
> ...
> >>> f(10, 20, a=1, b=2, c=3)         # a and b are used in two ways
> 10 20 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
> ```

Em tradução livre: "*Como os parâmetros à esquerda da `/` não são expostos como *keywords*, os seus nomes ficam disponíveis para serem usados em `**kwargs`*".

O primeiro `a` recebe o valor `10`, mas como ele é um parâmetro apenas posicional (graças à `/`), não há ambiguidade na chamada: eu sei que o `a=1` refere-se ao `kwargs`, já que o primeiro `a` não pode ser chamado pelo nome.

Comment: Então o que acontece é que **{'name' : 2} é a mesma coisa que name = 2, quando usado como parâmetro? Acho que entendi então valeu

Comment: @HenriqueHott Sim, inclusive [na documentação](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-argument) tem um exemplo que mostra isso

Answer (score 4):

Isso sempre causa confusão.

O * e ** são para "*desempacotar*" a variável recebida na função. Para mim, a palavra desempacotar pode causar confusão.

Normalmente usados como *args e **kwargs, o que eles fazem é:

```
*args - pegar os argumentos posicionais e transformar em uma tupla
**kwargs - pegar os argumentos nomeados e transformar em um dicionário
```

Veja o exemplo:

```
>>> def func(one, *args, **kwargs):
...     print(one)
...     print(args)
...     print(kwargs)
...
>>> func(1, "a", "b", 5, firstName="Joao", lastName="Silva")
1
('a', 'b', 5)
{'firstName': 'Joao', 'lastName': 'Silva'}
```

Perceba que o número `1` foi atribuído à variável `one`. Os demais parâmetros posicionais viraram um *tuple* chamado `args`. Já os parâmetros nomeados `firstName` e `lastName` viraram o dicionário `kwargs`

Para maiores detalhes visite [este](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) site.

Quanto ao /, ele indica que alguns parâmetros de função devem ser especificados posicionalmente e não podem ser usados como argumentos de palavra-chave.

Em outras palavras, ou melhor mostrando exemplo:

```
>>> def f(a, b, /, c, d, *, e, f):
...     print(c)
...
>>> f(10, 20, 30, d=40, e=50, f=60)
30

>>> f(a=10, b=20, c=30, d=40, e=50, f=60)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got some positional-only arguments passed as keyword arguments: 'a, b'

>>> f(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 4 positional arguments but 6 were given
>>> f(10, 20, 30, 40, e=50, f=60)
30
```

Exemplo modificado da [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

Ou seja, todos os parametros antes do `/` **não** podem ser nomeados.

Os parâmetros após o `*` **têm** que ser nomeados

Resumindo:

```
def name(somente_parametros_posicionais, /, parametros_posicionais_ou_nomeados, *, somente_parametros_nomeados):
```

Espero ter ajudado.